# Android: how to blink LED/flashlight rapidly

Tags: android, led, flashlight

I am trying to show some effects with the LED/flashlight, but it is not blinking rapidly. I even tried `sleep(2)`, but it takes time to blink. I want it to blink faster.

```
public void flash_effect() throws InterruptedException
{
    cam = Camera.open();     
    final Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        
    
    Thread a = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cam.stopPreview();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 
            }
        }
    };
    a.start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Where do you set your preview display?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

> Important: Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to
>   setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder). Without a surface, the camera will
>   be unable to start the preview.

```
cam.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

Maybe you should try this:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Switch on the cam for app's life
            if (mCamera == null) {
                // Turn on Cam
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }

            for (int i=0; i < times*2; i++) {
                toggleFlashLight();
                sleep(delay);
            }

            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
};

t.start();
```

Needed functions:

```
/** Turn the devices FlashLight on */
public void turnOn() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
    // Turn on LED
    mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
    mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    mCamera.setParameters(mParams);

    on = true;
}
}

/** Turn the devices FlashLight off */
public void turnOff() {
    // Turn off flashlight
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        if (mParams.getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
            mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
        }
    }
    on = false;
}

/** Toggle the flashlight on/off status */
public void toggleFlashLight() {
    if (!on) { // Off, turn it on
        turnOn();
    } else { // On, turn it off
        turnOff();
    }
}
```

and needed instance vars:

```
Camera mCamera;
Camera.Parameters mParameters;
int delay = 100; // in ms
```

Comment: Code from my own project here: [NotifFlashlight](http://sourceforge.net/p/notifflashlight/code/ci/master/tree/src/com/whd/notifflashlight/NotifFlashlightService.java#l132)

Comment: This did not work on my Nexus 5 with Lollipop. It did however work on Sony Z3 with KitKat. Needed a real PreviewDisplay

Comment: That is what the Android docs say (and what I have quoted), but because the free implementation this will work different on different devices. An Surface is also needed in the new package for the camera from which the description can be read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)