# How can I make the camera LED blink repeatedly?

Tags: android, camera, led, flashlight, blink

I have been working on a Morse Code app for a little while now and I am having trouble getting the camera flash to, well... flash. My ultimate goal is to type a brief message, press a single button, and have the LED flash the message in Morse Code by looping through the user entered message as a CharArray or something. The user should also be able to cancel the process at anytime during the flashing/translating. I can turn the light on and off at the touch of a toggle button easily enough with this code.

```
     mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                camera = Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            }
        }
    });
```

And I have gotten the LED to turn on, wait a given delay time, then turn itself off with a single button press with this code using a Handler and postDelayed().

```
Camera camera;

public void flash(int delay) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

But if I try to run the above flash function more than once on the same button press I get the following error at the Camera.open(); line at the start of the second function call.

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service**

I have done plenty of research on how to accomplish my goal of multiple flashes and the best/only viable solution is to use Thread.sleep(). It is my understanding that this would sleep the entire UI thread (since this is the only Thread I am using) and that is a bad practice. Are there any other solutions to my problem? I looked briefly into multiple threads but quickly became overwhelmed and wasn't sure that was the holy grail of answers I was hoping for.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How to blink led/flashlight rapidly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348418/android-how-to-blink-led-flashlight-rapidly)

Answer (score -1):

Two things comes to my mind.

1. Check Permissions specific to cameraFlashlight

   ```
   <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   ```
2. Try using android.hardware.camera2 API since Camera API is deprecated from Android API level 21.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but unfortunately it did not help. I had the permission and uses-feature already in the manifest so as to make the simple flashlight part of the app work. The working code to prove this is in my original post. I also attempted to import .camera2 instead of .camera API but Android Studio does not recognize it as a proper import.