# I want to make sos app but errors in blinking method

Tags: android

I am very new to android. Following is my code and I am getting these errors.

1. Cannot resolve symbol params.
2. Variable "`blinkDelay`" never assigned.
3. When i hover the mouse over "`Parameters`". it says "*android.hardware.Camera.Parameters Alt+Enter*".

In the following code:

```
blinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myString = "0101010101";
            long blinkDelay 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                } else {
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is my full `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.fusion.flashlight;     

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CameraManager mCameraManager;
private String mCameraId;
private ImageButton mTorchOnOffButton;
private ImageButton firstButton;
private Button blinkButton;
private Boolean isTorchOn;
private MediaPlayer media;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTorchOnOffButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
    firstButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1Switch);
    blinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blinking);

    isTorchOn = false;

    Boolean isFlashAvailable = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!isFlashAvailable) {

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error !!");
        alert.setMessage("Your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mTorchOnOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (isTorchOn) {
                    turnOffFlashLight();
                    isTorchOn = false;
                } else {
                    turnOnFlashLight();
                    isTorchOn = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    blinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myString = "0101010101";
            long blinkDelay 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                } else {
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });



}
public void turnOnFlashLight() {

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            playOnOffSound();
            mTorchOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_on);
            firstButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn11_on);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void turnOffFlashLight() {

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);
            playOnOffSound();
            mTorchOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_off);
            firstButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn11_off);



        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void playOnOffSound(){

    media = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    media.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    media.start();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(isTorchOn){
        turnOffFlashLight();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isTorchOn){
        turnOffFlashLight();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(isTorchOn){
        turnOnFlashLight();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For blinkDelay, you are missing an equal symbol when assigning,

For params, I cant see where do you create that variable.

And the other, alt+Enter is for autoImporting the Parameters class by Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

- Cannot resolve symbol params. `params not define`
- Variable "blinkDelay" never assigned.  `blinkDelay having no initial value`

  > long blinkDelay =50;
- When i hover the mouse over    "Parameters". it says
  "android.hardware.Camera.Parameters    Alt+Enter". `Alt+Enter for  import`

Comment: your 2nd problem is solved by using `long blinkDelay =50;` instead of ` long blinkDelay 50;

Comment: How to define params?

Comment: for 3rd error just click on `Parameters` and press `Alt+Enter`

Comment: When i press Alt+Enter. Camera.Parameter shows up but it is strike through text.

Comment: from where you got this code? can you tell me.. because params can be anything

Comment: yes. here is the link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595072/how-to-make-android-phone-flashlight-blink

Comment: `Camera.Parameter` thats ok

Comment: ` Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();`

Comment: use above line for params

Comment: and it is also saying... " android.hardware.camera is deprecated."

Comment: mCamera = Camera.open(mCameraId);